# How Can I Show An Avatar Image In Index Action in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: html, image, frameworks, zend-framework2

I saved only the name of the image in the database and the images are 
in the folder of images in the root folder called data.

I want to show the image in the index action and in a form action in Zend Framework 2.

I have tried this

```
<img width="162" height="44" src="/data/uploads/em_logo/n.jpg" alt="some_text">
```

but it isn´t working.

Comment: According to the path mentioned as `/data/...`, it will look for the `data` folder in `public` folder as `/public/data` and not the root `data` folder.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to do this is upload the image in the public folder, but if you need to save it in a private folder and show it you need to create a specified function to return the image.